# Groovy map of maps

Tags: groovy

I want to create a groovy map as follows

```
[
Apiname: ABC
ApiVersion: [
      1.2.3
      1.2.4
]
]
```

How do i go about creating this

I have tried with
Map<string, List> map = new HashMap

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean:

```
def myMap = [
    Apiname: "ABC",
    ApiVersion: [
        "1.2.3",
        "1.2.4"
    ]
]
```

Comment: Yes that is what I ment